# Scrabble Word Placement C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently writing a scrabble-like game in C#. I can get the computer to find the highest point value word that can be made using the current rack, however I have no idea how to check if that word is "Placeable" on the 15*15 Gameboard(2D Array: string[,]).

In it's default state(with no Letters on the board) all elements are set to 0.

Is allowed

```
---------------
-------H-------
-------E-------
-----FILL------
-------L-------
-------O-------
---------------
```

How can I check if the word is not For example:

Is Not Allowed

```
 ---------------
 -H-------------
 -E-------------
FILL------------ <-- F is out of bounds
 -L-------------
 -O-------------
 ---------------
```

Is Not Allowed

```
 ---------------
 -H-------------
 -E-W-----------
 -L-O-----------
 -L-R-----------
 FOLL----------- <-- Fill is overlapping with O
 ---D-----------
```

Comment: I think you'll have to figure this out for yourself - check bounds and check existing letters in place. There's no obvious algorithm for this, so we'd need to see your code to tell you what to do. But it can't be *that* hard. On the bounds checking: don't you already know this because you'd need to look up triple-letter score tiles etc.?

Comment: Also "2D Array: string[,]" - you've got a string for every square? not a char?

Comment: Just a suggestion: what if, instead of looking at the tiles in the rack first, you identified all of the locations on the board where a word could go? I realize this is easier said than done, but thinking about the problem a different way might lead you to a breakthrough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The paper, "[The worlds fastest Scrabble engine](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s06/www/lectures/scrabble.pdf)" (PDF), is from 1988 and describes an efficient Scrabble engine.  It's short and surprisingly readable!

Comment: Great little find! I will have to give it a read as both a competitive Scrabble player and someone who has tried to implement it in J2ME.

Comment: @Jeff +1 for a good answer with the added bonus of some very interesting reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I learned how to do this based on the F# [SharpScrabble](http://code.google.com/p/sharpscrabble/) project. Even if you don't know F# (like me), you'll get a feel for how the author decided to do this.

The big things to me were:

- Using a `Coordinate` system to find `Tiles`
- Populating the `Board` with `Squares` that can hold a tile (letter) but also hold score information
- `Tile` represents a letter, both in the player's letter bank and also on the board
- `Move` that represents a player's placement of letters
- Implementing the `IComparable` on coordinates and tiles to make sorting easier
- Computing `Runs` which represent the words a move would place, to compute score

Overall, a really good primer on beginning to wrap your head around a Scrabble engine. I was able to port much of that code into C# without knowing F# a lick, so it shouldn't be terrible for anyone else.